# JOIN with multiple columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have the following two tables in postgresql:

```
     TABLE: act_codes
    ===================
     activity  act_desc
    ____________________
        1      sleeping
        2      commuting
        3      eating
        4      working
     TABLE: data
    ===================
    act1_1     act_1_2     act1_3     act1_4
    ---------------------------------------------
      1         1           3           4
      1         2           2           3
      1         1           2           2
      1         2           2           3
      1         1           1           2
      1         1           3           4
      1         2           2           4
      1         1           1           3
      1         3           3           4
      1         1           4           4
```

The act_codes table is basically a table of activities (with a code and a description), and the data table contains the activity codes for (in this case) 4 different times (act1_1, act1_2, act1_3 and act1_4).

I am trying to query this to get a table of counts for each activity.  I have managed to do this for each individual column (in this case act1_4) like this:

```
    SELECT A.act_code, A.act_desc, COUNT (act1_4) 
    FROM act_codes AS A
    LEFT JOIN data AS D 
    ON D.act1_4 = A.act_code
    GROUP BY A.act_code, A.act_desc;
```

Which works fine for that column, but I have a very large number of columns to work through, so would prefer it if there was a way to do this within an SQL query.

---

I now have the following query (many thanks to banazs):

```
    SELECT
        ac.act_code, 
        ac.act_desc,
        act_time,
        COUNT(activity) AS act_count
    FROM
        (SELECT
            UNNEST(array['act1_1','act1_2','act1_3','act1_4']) AS act_time,
            UNNEST(array[d.act1_1, d.act1_2, d.act1_3, d.act1_4]) AS activity
        FROM
            data d) t
    RIGHT JOIN
        act_codes ac ON t.activity = ac.act_code
    GROUP BY
        ac.act_code, 
        ac.act_desc,
        act_time, activity
    ORDER BY 
        activity, 
        act_time
    ;
```

Which outputs:

```
    act_code        act_desc        act_time        act_count
    ---------------------------------------------------------
        1           sleeping            act1_1          10
        1           sleeping            act1_2          6
        1           sleeping            act1_3          2
        2           commuting           act1_2          3
        2           commuting           act1_3          4
        2           commuting           act1_4          2
        3           eating              act1_2          1
        3           eating              act1_3          3
        3           eating              act1_4          3
        4           working             act1_3          1
        4           working             act1_4          5
```

Which is basically what I was looking for.  Ideally, the rows with zero counts could be added in somehow, but gI am guessing that this is perhaps best done as a separate process (e.g. constructing a crosstab in R or something).

Comment: Please confirm: the `data` table has a separate column for each time?

Comment: Redo the db design.

Comment: The columns in the data table correspond to time segments (e.g. act1_1 is the first 5 mins, act1_2 is the second,etc..). Is not my design - so I have to work with this shape of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive the table described above, the query is need to be redesigned a bit.

First you have to create an auxiliary table which contains the [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) of the column names and the activities:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    act_codes ac
-- if you have lots of columns you can query their 
-- names from the information_schema.columns system 
-- table 
CROSS JOIN -- the CROSS JOIN combine each rows from both tables
    (SELECT 
        column_name 
    FROM 
        information_schema.columns 
    WHERE 
        table_schema = 'stackoverflow' 
        AND table_name = 'data' 
        AND column_name LIKE 'act%') cn 
;
```

Adding the number of activites to this:

```
SELECT 
    ac.act_code,
    ac.act_desc,
    cn.column_name,
    -- the COALESCE add zero values where the original is NULL
    COALESCE(ad.act_no ,0) AS act_no
FROM
    act_codes ac
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT 
        column_name
    FROM 
        information_schema.columns 
    WHERE 
        table_schema = 'stackoverflow' 
        AND table_name = 'data' 
        AND column_name LIKE 'act%') cn
-- you need to use LEFT JOIN to preserve all rows
-- from the cartesian product
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        t.column_name,
        t.act_code,
        COUNT(*) AS act_no
    FROM
        (SELECT
            UNNEST(array['act1_1','act1_2','act1_3','act1_4']) AS column_name,
            UNNEST(array[d.act1_1, d.act1_2, d.act1_3, d.act1_4]) AS act_code
        FROM
            data d) t
    GROUP BY
        t.column_name,
        t.act_code) ad ON ad.act_code = ac.act_code AND ad.column_name = cn.column_name 
;
```

To format the result to looks like yours is possible, but a little bit messy. You need to create two tables, the first has to contain the result set of the previous query, the second the column names.

```
CREATE TABLE acts AS
    SELECT 
        ac.act_code,
        ac.act_desc,
        cn.column_name,
        COALESCE(ad.act_no ,0) AS act_no
    FROM
        act_codes ac
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT 
            column_name
        FROM 
            information_schema.columns 
        WHERE 
            table_schema = 'stackoverflow' 
            AND table_name = 'data' 
            AND column_name LIKE 'act%') cn
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            t.column_name,
            t.act_code,
            COUNT(*) AS act_no
        FROM
            (SELECT
                UNNEST(array['act1_1','act1_2','act1_3','act1_4']) AS column_name,
                UNNEST(array[d.act1_1, d.act1_2, d.act1_3, d.act1_4]) AS act_code
            FROM
                data d) t
        GROUP BY
            t.column_name,
            t.act_code) ad ON ad.act_code = ac.act_code AND ad.column_name = cn.column_name 
;

CREATE TABLE column_names AS
    SELECT 
        column_name
    FROM 
        information_schema.columns 
    WHERE 
        table_schema = 'stackoverflow' 
        AND table_name = 'data' 
        AND column_name LIKE 'act%'
;
```

Install the [tablefunc extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html).

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

It provides the crosstab() function and using this you can get the described output.

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM   
    crosstab(
        'SELECT act_desc, column_name, act_no FROM acts ORDER  BY 1',  
        'SELECT * FROM column_names'
    )  
AS 
    ct (
        "act_desc" text, 
        "act1_1" int, 
        "act1_2" int, 
        "act1_3" int, 
        "act1_4" int
        );
;

+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| act_desc  | act1_1 | act1_2 | act1_3 | act1_4 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| commuting |      0 |      3 |      4 |      2 |
| eating    |      0 |      1 |      3 |      3 |
| sleeping  |     10 |      6 |      2 |      0 |
| working   |      0 |      0 |      1 |      5 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can "unpivot" the data using `UNNEST`:

```
   SELECT
        UNNEST(array['act1_1','act1_2','act1_3','act1_4']) AS column_name,
        UNNEST(array[d.act1_1, d.act1_2, d.act1_3, d.act1_4]) AS value
    FROM
        data d
    ;
```

Count the activities:

```
SELECT
    ac.act_code, 
    ac.act_desc,
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (SELECT
        UNNEST(array['act1_1','act1_2','act1_3','act1_4']) AS column_name,
        UNNEST(array[d.act1_1, d.act1_2, d.act1_3, d.act1_4]) AS val
    FROM
        data d) t
INNER JOIN
    act_codes ac ON t.val = ac.act_code
GROUP BY
    ac.act_code, 
    ac.act_desc 
;
```

Comment: I just tried that, and it works as a reshaping step, but I am not sure how to convert this into the table of counts that I am looking to generate.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @banazs - that is really useful in terms of helping me understand how to structure queries like this.

However, I still have a difficulty in arranging the query to split the output so that there is a column of counts for each time.  Apologies - I think the labeling here is a bit confusing (act1_1 is referring to activities done at time_1, and 'act1_2' refers to time_2, etc..).  The result I am trying to get to looks like this:

```
    act_code    act_desc        count_act1_1    count_act1_2    count_act1_3    count_act1_4
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1       sleeping            10              6               2               0
        2       commuting           0               3               4               2
        3       eating              0               1               3               3
        4       working             0               0               1               5
```

I am not concerned about the output being in columns - I can easily reshape it, but it is important that the zero's are present in the table. Is this possible?

Comment: I created a new answer to this, it's a little bit complicated so feel free to ask about it.